# Handling duplicate records in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

Suppose I have a set of records which I know to be unique based on some other record and an e-mail, thusly:

```
class Signup(models.Model):
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, related_name='activities')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    # many addtional fields here not relevant to question
```

Then, I have a model form:

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Signup
        exclude = [ 'activity' ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.activity = kwargs.pop('activity')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['commit'] = False
        m = super(SignupForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        m.activity = self.activity
        m.save()
        return m
```

Suppose a user goes in a fills out the form under the activity, then realizes they made an error in the form, clicks the back button, makes changes, then clicks submit again.

Without any modifications to the code above, a duplicate record for that activity and email would be created.

What I want to know is how I can force the form to update, rather than create, a record if it finds a match for the entered e-mail.

I tried this code:

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Signup
        exclude = [ 'activity' ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.activity = kwargs.pop('activity')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['commit'] = False
        try:
            self.instance = Signup.objects.get(email=self.cleaned_data['email'], activity=self.activity)
        except Signup.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        m = super(SignupForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        m.activity = self.activity
        m.save()
        return m
```

However, looks like this causes the form to ignore all new information for some reason (I have [debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) running and examining the query confirms that none of the fields are being changed!)

Is there an accepted way of handling this?

#### Further request

Is there any way to do this while still using the `ModelForm`'s built-in `save` function? So far the answers seem to suggest that this is impossible, which is, I'm sorry, ridiculous.

Comment: You want this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create From the view level. It returns the object and Boolean in a tuple. Unpack the tuple and then if the boolean is false, update.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
try:
    self.instance = Signup.objects.get(email=self.cleaned_data['email'], activity=self.activity)
except Signup.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

With:

```
obj, created = Signup.objects.get_or_create(\
                    email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
                    activity=self.activity)
if created:
   print 'its a new one, hooray!'
else:
   print 'the object exists!'
```

More information on [`get_or_create`](http://django.me/get_or_create).

Comment: I'm aware of the `get_or_create` function... So you're saying it's **impossible** to use `ModelForm`'s built-in save function for this purpose? That's a drag.

Comment: And then I guess I follow it up with `Signup.objects.filter(pk=obj.pk).update(**self.cleaned_data)`?

Comment: If you pass the form an instance, it will update it instead of saving it. You'd still have to query the db manually.